# How to compute studentized residuals for a regression grouped by 2 characteristics on python?

Tags: python, statistics, regression, pandas-groupby, analysis

I am working on my bachelor thesis and I have to compute something called empirical leanness indicator. For that I need to obtain the studentized residual of each observation. Each observation is a company in a specific year. I ran a regression analysis by regressing the natural logarithm of inventory levels on the natural logarithm of revenues. I also grouped the regression by industry (SIC code) and by currency (USD or CAD). Now I have to find the studentized residuals for each of these observations, which are contained in one data frame (sample size is 62739 and there are 494 different regressions), accounting for the fact that each observation must be matched with the regression for its SIC code and currency.

I tried so many codes, with different ideas, but none worked.

This is my entire code for now (invt means total inventories, revt means total revenue, and conm means company name):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm

df = pd.read_csv('Compustat data.csv')

df.dropna(inplace=True)

df = df.drop(df[df.invt == 0].index)
df = df.drop(df[df.revt <= 0].index)

df = df[df.duplicated('conm') | df.duplicated('conm', keep = 'last')]

df['invt'] = np.log(df['invt'])
df['revt'] = np.log(df['revt'])

def regress(df, invt, revt):
    Y = df[invt]
    X = df[revt]
    X['intercept'] = 1.
    result = sm.OLS(Y, X).fit()
    return result.params

df2 = df.groupby(['sic', 'curcd']).apply(regress, 'invt', ['revt'])
```